# Linear system of equation solving method

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I need to minimize $6x+4y+8z$ subject to $xyz=1000$.

I use the following theorem:

[image]

So:

grad $f=(6,4,8)$, grad $\lambda g=\lambda(yz,xz,xy)$

So when I equate these:

$6=\lambda yz$

$4=\lambda xz$

$8=\lambda xy$

So I'm not sure how to solve this. My method is to suppose that $y=1$ then $\lambda= 8/ x, \lambda=6/z$ So the I proceed with :

$4=(8/x)xz \Rightarrow z=1/2 \Rightarrow \lambda=12 \Rightarrow 8/x=12 \Rightarrow x=2/3$

But then $xyz=1000$, so my solution does not align with this.

Is there any way or trick to solve this? I've been trying different methods (loads of them), but nothing seems to get what I need.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have four unknowns ($x,y,z,\lambda$) so you need four equations: the three from $\nabla f - \lambda \nabla g=0$ and also $xyz=1000$.

From there, one nice method is to take advantage of the fact that all four equations have a constant on one side and a product of three of the variables on the other side. You can multiply each equation by one variable to get $\lambda xyz$ on one side, then set all the equations equal to each other to get some nice simple relations between the variables.